# How to login in the form using input id in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

The `input` element don't have `name` attribute, so I have to use `id` of `input` element. Originally I used this code:

```
casper.start('https://mp.weixin.qq.com/', function() { 
    this.fillSelectors('form#login-form', { 
        'input[id="account"]':  usr, 
        'input[id="password"]': passwd 
    }, true); 
});
```

Just won't work, so I tried `fillXPath()`,

```
casper.start('https://mp.weixin.qq.com/', function() { 
    this.fillXPath('form#login-form', { 
        '//input[@id="account"]':  usr, 
        '//input[@id="password"]': passwd 
    }, true); 
});
```

Also not work. FYI:

```
 # phantomjs --version
 1.9.7
 # casperjs --version
 1.1.0-beta3
```

Running report:

```
root@do1:/var/www/casperjs-phantomjs# casperjs test.js aaaaa@qq.com mysecret
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://mp.weixin.qq.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://mp.weixin.qq.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected ./jquery-1.11.1.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3 https://mp.weixin.qq.com/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#login-form'
[debug] [remote] Set "null" field value to aaaaa@qq.com
[debug] [remote] Set "null" field value to *******
[info] [remote] submitting form to unknown, HTTP GET
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 970ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://mp.weixin.qq.com/?, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://mp.weixin.qq.com/?"
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected ./jquery-1.11.1.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://mp.weixin.qq.com/? (HTTP 200)
Page url is https://mp.weixin.qq.com/?
Page title is 公众平台登录
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 1532ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 1549ms
```

Login page is : `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/`

Comment: Did you try by clicking the submit button?

Comment: @Fanch Yes, sure. But if you mean by using CasperJS click, I was not. By the way, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, CasperJS click, see [casperjs fill and click not working as i expected cannot click button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516182/casperjs-fill-and-click-not-working-as-i-expected-cannot-click-button/22527446#22527446)

Comment: @Fanch Thank you, I've tried, but still same result as mine.

Comment: Apparently your selectors are wrong, form `unknown`, field value : `null`, can you show us the html?

Answer (score 0):

**fillSelectors** should work fine, but you might use **sendKeys** and **click** as a workaround:

```
casper.start('https://mp.weixin.qq.com/', function() {
    this.sendKeys('input[id="account"]', "my_account");
    this.sendKeys('input[id="password"]', "my_password");
    this.click('input[type="submit"]');
});
```

Comment: Still won't work, btw, `fillSelectors` doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Use css3 selectors for casper.fillSelectors http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors
    casper.start('https://mp.weixin.qq.com/', function() {

```
    this.fillSelectors('form#login-form', { 
        '#account':  usr, 
        '#password': passwd 
    }, true); 
});
```